# How to know if I have DDS installed?

Tags: ros, robotics, data-distribution-service, ros2

I'm a bit of a noob on ROS2 and I'm starting to learn about the DDS protocol and its implementation on ROS2. So far, I've read that ROS2 already comes with eProsima Fast RTPS, however, I would like to make sure if this is really installed or not. How can I confirm this? Is there a terminal command or something I can do to test it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check if you installed ros2 from apt is

```sh
apt list --installed ros-eloquent-fastrtps
```

or you could check the directory `/opt/ros/eloquent/include/fastrtps`